# Hello World Magento Plugin

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm new to magento & am trying to get a simple plugin working.

When a user adds a product to the basket I'd like magento to display a dialog box with some text in it.

Can anyone provide a link to a guide to this or something similar? 
I'm using magento2

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks for that,

I found a tutorial and this is what I have atm, the plugin looks to be enabled as far as I can see.

What I'm trying to get to working is a message to display when a user adds a product to the cart.

Currently the text on the add to cart button changes to 'Adding..' and hangs. How can I debug this?

Thanks for that,

I found a tutorial and this is what I have atm, the plugin looks to be enabled as far as I can see.

What I'm trying to get to working is a message to display when a user adds a product to the cart.

Currently the text on the add to cart button changes to 'Adding..' and hangs. How can I debug this or fix this?

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AddToCartMessage\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\CartInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;

class AddToCartMessage{

private $messageManager;

public fucntion __construct(MessageManager $messageManager){
  $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
}

public afterAddProduct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\CartInterface $cart,     $result){
$this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage('Testing');

return result;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a couple ways to achieve what you're trying to do. The cleanest way would be to utilize event observers. Here's a link to their documentation - [Magento 2 - Events and Observers](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html).

A quick overview:

1. Create an `etc/frontend/events.xml` file.
2. Create an observer for the `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event.
3. Inject the `\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface` into your observer class.

   ```
   public function __construct (
       \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
   ) {
       $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
   }
   ```

The message manager will display a notification after the item has been added. To show a popup, you should look into M2's JS components - [JavaScript Developer Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/bk-javascript-dev-guide.html).

Comment: Thanks for that, I updated my original question with some code from a tutorial I found.

Comment: There's a spelling error in that code. "public fucntion __construct" should be "public function __construct"

Comment: I would also suggest using an observer instead of a plugin. Plugins are fine, but can sometimes lead to unexpected behavior depending on the method you're plugging into. 

Here's a link to the Cart/Add controller where the "checkout_cart_add_product_complete" event is fired, https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php#L119.